# Selecting a value contained in a conditional group by in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, conditional-statements, case

Depending on the @dataCase value, the result would be either grouped by **country** or by **country and city**.

```
SELECT 
    User.CountryId AS Country   
FROM User
GROUP BY User.CountryId,
    CASE
        WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN User.City
    END
```

But in the case when the result is grouped by City I can't get the value. It shows the following error.

*"Column 'User.City' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."*

```
SELECT 
    User.CountryId AS Country,
    CASE 
        WHEN @dataCase != 1 THEN '-' 
        WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN User.City
    END AS City     
FROM User
GROUP BY User.CountryId,
    CASE
        WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN User.City
    END
```

Is it at all possible to select a value that is inside a conditional group by in SQL?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` expression needs to match the `GROUP BY` expression.  So this should work:

```
SELECT u.CountryId AS Country,
       (CASE WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN u.City
        END) AS City     
FROM User u
GROUP BY User.CountryId,
         (CASE WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN u.City
          END);
```

If you want `'-'` instead:

```
SELECT u.CountryId AS Country,
       (CASE WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN u.City ELSE '-'
        END) AS City     
FROM User u
GROUP BY User.CountryId,
         (CASE WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN u.City ELSE '-'
          END);
```

Comment: Why not simply SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY?

Comment: @jarlh . . . That is a very reasonable solution.  The OP is explicitly asking about `group by`, but `select distinct` is probably more appropriate for what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any aggregation function involved, you can use `DISTINCT` instead :

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.CountryId AS Country, 
       (CASE WHEN @dataCase = 1 THEN u.City 
             ELSE '-' 
        END) AS City     
FROM [User] u;
```